# Jackson polymorphic deserialization fails: different classes, same identical code

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have three classes: Request ( abstract ), RequestCreateContract, RequestUpdateContract. Strangely RequestUpdateContract failed to be deserialized. I have tried to copy-paste the  RequestCreateContract code into RequestUpdateContract and it continues to fail: just Class name and Constructor names were changed. On the other hand, the RequestCreateContract works without any problem.

Reported exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "contract" (class mypackage.net.protocol.request.RequestUpdateContract), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "login"])
```

Here is the code.
Request ( superclass )

```
package mypackage.net.protocol.request;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

import mypackage.net.protocol.Login;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RequestUpdateContract.class, name = "RequestUpdateContract"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RequestCreateContract.class, name = "RequestCreateContract"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RequestDeleteContract.class, name = "RequestDeleteContract"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RequestFindContract.class, name = "RequestFindContract"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RequestGetContract.class, name = "RequestGetContract")


}
)
public abstract class Request {


    protected Login login;

    @JsonCreator
    public Request(@JsonProperty("login") Login login){

        this.login=login;
    }

    public Request(){

    }

    @JsonProperty("login")
    public Login login(){

        return login;
    }

}
```

RequestCreateContract

```
package mypackage.net.protocol.request;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import mypackage.datamodel.contract.Contract;
import mypackage.datamodel.contract.dealinfo.DealInfo;
import mypackage.net.protocol.Login;


public class RequestCreateContract  extends Request{

    /*
    DealInfo dealInfo;

    @JsonCreator
    public RequestCreateContract(
            @JsonProperty("login") Login login,
            @JsonProperty("dealinfo") DealInfo dealInfo){

        super(login);
        this.dealInfo=dealInfo;
    }

    @JsonProperty("dealinfo")
    public DealInfo dealInfo(){

        return dealInfo;
    }
    */

    Contract contract;

    @JsonCreator
    public RequestCreateContract(

            @JsonProperty("contract") Contract contract,
            @JsonProperty("login") Login login){

        super(login);
        this.contract=contract;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contract")
    public Contract contract(){

        return contract;
    }

}
```

RequestUpdateContract

```
package mypackage.net.protocol.request;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import mypackage.datamodel.contract.Contract;
import mypackage.datamodel.contract.dealinfo.DealInfo;
import mypackage.net.protocol.Login;


public class RequestUpdateContract extends Request{

    /*
    DealInfo dealInfo;

    @JsonCreator
    public RequestCreateContract(
            @JsonProperty("login") Login login,
            @JsonProperty("dealinfo") DealInfo dealInfo){

        super(login);
        this.dealInfo=dealInfo;
    }

    @JsonProperty("dealinfo")
    public DealInfo dealInfo(){

        return dealInfo;
    }
    */

    Contract contract;

    @JsonCreator
    public RequestUpdateContract(

            @JsonProperty("contract") Contract contract,
            @JsonProperty("login") Login login){

        super(login);
        this.contract=contract;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contract")
    public Contract contract(){

        return contract;
    }

}
```

I hope you can reproduce the problem. Those classes are part of a shared project between client and server applications.

Answer (score 0):

It is a synchronization problem, proven by the fact that changing name to the RequestUpdateContract by refactoring the class name brings to another error ( Jackson unable to resolve the new class name ).